# Compiler doesnt match the right brackets in razor code

Tags: c#, razor

I'm trying to build an HTML table in razor code where I put two items on each row. I thought of the aproach underneath. However, the compiler won't match the correct brackets with one another. Is there some way to get around this?

```
 for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0 || i % 2 == 0)
        { //this bracket matches...
            <tr>
        }

//<td>plot item data here</td>

        if (i % 2 == 1 || i == items.Length - 1)
        {
            </tr>
        } //... with this bracket
    }
```

Comment: `@Html.Raw("<tr>")` and `@Html.Raw("</tr>")` is probably closer to what you're after.

Comment: Use `@: </tr>` or `<text></tr><text>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:** I apologize, I misunderstood the purpose of the code. If I understand correctly, you want to get 2 items from a list and place them next to each other, except when there's an odd count, where the last  would only have one item?

If so, this should work, I think:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= list.Count + 1; i += 2)
{
    <tr>
    if (i < list.Count)
    {
        <td>@(list[i - 1])</td>
        <td>@(list[i])</td>
    }
    else if (i == list.Count)
    {
        <td>@(list[i - 1])</td>
    }
    </tr>
}
```

*updated with small bug-fix*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This was not quite what i was looking for. I wasnt planning on showing different data based on a condition. I would like to show 2 items per table row. So I was trying to do that with a conditional <tr> tag. And thats when i ran into the problem of the wrong brackets matching.

Comment: There really no need to see more code as posted code clearly demonstrate the issue caused by misunderstanding of switching between c# and html context in razor views.

Comment: @IvovanLeeuwen I misunderstood the purpose of the code. I've updated the post. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance you're second bracket would never get applied because of the if statement.

You could put an else on there and put the closing bracket in there also and the compiler will probably be happy.

Edit
Or you could increment your loop by 2 each time and completely remove the if from the loop.

Comment: This explanation has nothing to do with problem OP has (switching between c# and html context)... Also suggestion to change code look reasonable.